# The right mouse button does not give OnMouseUp when it is released outside the target

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, right-click

As shown below, the OnMouseUp event is monitored.

When the left mouse button is pressed down within the form, and dragged outside the form, and then released, the OnMouseUp event can be fired.

When the right mouse button is pressed down within the form, and dragged outside the form, and then released, the OnMouseUp event cannot be fired.

Could you help to comment how to correct / work around this behavior for the right mouse button ?

```
unit Unit26;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm26 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
        TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form26: TForm26;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm26.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('FormMouseUp');
end;

end.
```

The related code (from TControl) is shown below.

```
procedure TControl.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseUp) then FOnMouseUp(Self, Button, Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TControl.DoMouseUp(var Message: TWMMouse; Button: TMouseButton);
begin
  if not (csNoStdEvents in ControlStyle) then
    with Message do MouseUp(Button, KeysToShiftState(Keys) + MouseOriginToShiftState, XPos, YPos);
end;

procedure TControl.WMLButtonUp(var Message: TWMLButtonUp);
begin
  inherited;
  if csCaptureMouse in ControlStyle then MouseCapture := False;
  if csClicked in ControlState then
  begin
    Exclude(FControlState, csClicked);
    if PtInRect(ClientRect, SmallPointToPoint(Message.Pos)) then
      Click;
  end;
  DoMouseUp(Message, mbLeft);
end;

procedure TControl.WMRButtonUp(var Message: TWMRButtonUp);
begin
  inherited;
  DoMouseUp(Message, mbRight);
end;
```

However, it seems that WMRButtonUp will not be fired if the ight mouse button is released outside form. The MSDN of [WM_LBUTTONUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WM_RBUTTONUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646243(v=vs.85).aspx) look quite similar. Could you help to comment why WMLButtonUp will be fired but WMRButtonUp will not be fired in this case ?

Comment: To get the mouse events from outside the form it has to be captured (see [Mouse Movement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153550(v=vs.85).aspx)). And the source from TControl points out, this is not done on right mouse button

Comment: @SirRufo Thank you for your helpful comments ! Could you help to comment how to correctly override WMRMouseDown and WMRMouseUp to handle mouse capture ? :D

Comment: Do it the same way as the vcl code for the other button